# Gas generator exhaust for roll control

Tags: rockets, flight-control

Can the exhaust from the turbopump of a rocket engine be used for roll control if a rocket only has 1 engine?
Did the falcon 1 rocket control roll this way?

Comment: What has your prior research shown you?

Comment: The spin-stabilisation tag might not be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

From [here(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_Satellite_Launch_Vehicle#Second_stage_(PS2))

> ... while roll control is provided by a Hot gas Reaction Control Motor (HRCM) that ejects hot gases diverted from gas generator of Vikas engine.

Unfortunately, the source cited in the above article doesn't appear to be a valid link any more.